# iptables port forward stopped working

Tags: iptables

I have a ubuntu 17.04, and I configured DNS, DHCP and iptables, everything was working as expected.
Now just port forwards do not work.  DNS and DHCP and internet is all available to computers in the private subnet.

Here is my setup:

```
eno1 is the exterior/public NIC
enp2s0f1 is the private subnet NIT

myubuntu enp2s0f1 ip:  192.168.0.1

ubuntu@myubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -L --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         



ubuntu@myubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -t nat --line-numbers -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http to:192.168.0.51:8080

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            



ubuntu@myubuntu:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.6.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
10.10.6.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eno1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp2s0f1
```

I' m thinking it has to be something silly...   But I can not find it.
Any help will be appreciated.

I  flipped the POSTROUTE MASQUERADE to the WAN nic and I have the NAT forwards working for my RDP (3389).
However another NAT going to a different server does not work???? This NAT is mapped from port 80 on the router to port 8080 on another cpu, and it does not work.

```
 ubuntu@myubuntu:/$ sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L --line-numbers
 Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 340 packets, 29199 bytes)
 num      pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                         destination         
 1           1       52 DNAT       tcp  --  eno1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9997 to:192.168.0.4:3389
 2           0        0 DNAT       tcp  --  eno1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:192.168.0.51:8080
 3           0        0 DNAT       tcp  --  eno1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:81 to:192.168.0.51:8080
```

For NAT #1 I can see packets flowing into it, but for NATs 2 & 3 I do not? Nothing is blocking these ports locally.

Any suggestions?